# Load component after api is fetched

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

I am fetching json from API and then I want to display the component

```
 const [jsonCat, setjsonCat] = useState([]);
  
 useEffect(() => {
    refreshCat();
  }, []);
    
 const refreshCat = async () => {
        try {
          console.log("refreshing categories");
          setjsonCat([]);
    
          getCat().then((response) => {
            setjsonCat(response);
          });
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
      };
    
 const CarousalLoop = (props) => {
            const BANNER_Hs = 1;
        
            if (jsonCat.length == 0) {
              return <View></View>;
            }
         
            const listItemstest = jsonCat.map((link) => {
              console.log(link.name);
              <View>
                <Text style={{ color: "red" }}>{link.name}</Text>
              </View>;
            });
            return (
              <View style={{ height: 220, backgroundColor: "brown" }}>
                {listItemstest}
              </View>
            );
          };
```

And Finally my render component has

```
{jsonCat.length ? <CarousalLoop /> : <ActivityIndicator />}
```

When I run this code , Activity indicator is shown until API request is fetched and then json is also received properly ,               **console.log(link.name)**
is printing the names correctly but  CarousalLoop is displayed without any listitems (just brown view component is shown) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you use **return** keyword

```
const listItemstest = jsonCat.map((link) => {
         console.log(link.name);
         return(
               <View>
                <Text style={{ color: "red" }}>{link.name}</Text>
               </View>
              )
            });
```

Or wrap in **parenthesis**

```
      const listItemstest = jsonCat.map((link) => (
              <View>
                <Text style={{ color: "red" }}>{link.name}</Text>
              </View>;
            ));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the list of items to render from listItemstest, like this.

```
const listItemstest = jsonCat.map((link) => {
              console.log(link.name);
              return <View>
                <Text style={{ color: "red" }}>{link.name}</Text>
              </View>;
            });
```

Comment: The return keyword is important - without that, you are just returning a list of undefineds.